# HP laptop power cord will not fit into outlets on power strip

Tags: laptop, surge-protection, ac-adapter, hp, powerstrip

My electrical outlet sparked and damaged the power cord that came with my laptop. I ordered two replacements, one from HP and the other from another reseller of spare parts.

When it was time to charge my laptop battery, I decided to not use the wall outlet that sparked and instead tried to use a power strip. Unfortunately neither of the two replacement power cords will go into the power strip. I push, but they will only go halfway in. I'm guessing there is a reason for this, but I don't know why. I can't use another wall outlet, they're sparking too. I'm have an electrician come to fix the issue soon.

But for now, can someone please tell me why my laptop's power cord will not plug into any of the outlets on my power strip? I intend to buy a surge protector later, but will I have the same problem? Is there a certain type of power strip or surge protector needed for laptops?

Specifications if needed:

The laptop is an HP Envy model 17-ce1010nr

The bottom of the laptop says Input 19.5V 3.33A

The adapter says 65W Input 100-200V 1.7A 50-60Hz Output 19.5V 3.33A 65.0W

The power cord says Longwell E55349 7A 125V. One end says LP-30D, the other end says LS-18N.

The power strip says 125V 15A 60Hz.

[image: Power Strip]

[image: Power Cords]

Comment: There are different plugs in the whole world. You mention 125V, does that mean you are in the USA?

Comment: You failed to provide screenshots of the plugs and the power strip. Impossible to answer your question with an answer without all the information necessary to do so

Comment: I think your problem is more serious than that : If you're getting sparks from all wall outlets, it's possible that you have a short-circuit inside the computer. I suggest using a repair-shop.

Comment: Yes I'm in the USA. I didn't fail to provide pictures. I tried and it wasn't letting me. That's why I wrote everything out.

Comment: "If you're getting sparks from all wall outlets, it's possible that you have a short-circuit inside the computer. I suggest using a repair-shop." I'm sorry, I should have specified that it's not only my laptop that sparks when plugging it into the wall outlet. It's everything. Hairdryer, lamps, etc.

Comment: Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: I edited my post to include a link to the pictures. https://imgur.com/a/gZAtjkp

Comment: You didn't use the built-in ability to upload files in the question editor, you should do that, but when you say the plug doesn't fit.  Does it not fit when it's the only thing that is being plugged into it?

Comment: You could try another type of power strip, but I wouldn't do that as long as the there is an electrical problem in the house. I suggest waiting for the electrician, and getting at least a power surge protection.